# 3 x 3 grid of posts on the home page

Tags: theme-development, homepage, frontpage

I'm using Wordpress as more CMS than blog, and I want to create a theme that uses 9 specific posts on the home page.

I don't want those posts to show up in other lists. I don't want other posts to accidentally override these posts. My rough sense is that I'd put the 9 posts in a single category (`front`) and then give each one a placement tag (`top center` / `middle left` / etc) and build a [static front page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page) around that.

Am I on the right track here?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to use a [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types). This way, these posts won't show up as custom post types by default are excluded from the main query.

You can just then create your page and create a custom query with [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to pull in this 9 posts

**1. CREATE CUSTOM POST TYPE**

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'acme_product',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Products' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

**2. CREATE YOUR CUSTOM QUERY**

```
<?php

// The Query
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'acme_product',
  'posts_per_page' => 9
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

All you have to do know is setup your page template, set it as front page and add your 9 posts

I hope this helps

Comment: Did my answer solved your problem. If yes, please consider accepting my answer by clicking on the check mark on the left of my answer below the up/down arrow. If not, what problem do you still have?